# ¿Por qué "manzana" es un conjunto de casas?

Tags: etimología, historia, comida

La entrada en el DLE para [**manzana**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OItjStD), recoge como segunda acepción:

> 2. f. Espacio urbano, edificado o destinado a la edificación, generalmente cuadrangular, delimitado por calles por todos sus lados.

Esta acepción aparece desde el [**Diccionario de autoridades**](http://web.frl.es/DA.html):

> MANZANA. Se llama tambien el conjunto de varias casas contiguas, que forman una a modo de Isla, con las calles que las rodéan. Latín. *Domuum insula.*

Esta acepción no aparece en los diccionarios anteriores que se pueden consultar mediante el NTLLE: solo figura la acepción "fruto del manzano".

¿Cómo adquirió el "fruto del manzano" esa nueva acepción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el lingüista Juan Ramón Lodares Marrodán ([fuente](https://www.api.cat/noticias/por-que-se-llama-manzana-a-una-isla-de-casas/)), en el siglo XVII ya aparece *manzana* en el vocabulario de los arquitectos españoles como sinónimo de bloque de casas, derivados de los términos franceses *maçon* 'albañil' y de *maison* 'casa'. Efectivamente, en el CORDE podemos ver un ejemplo de uso por esas fechas:

> *Mayo. Año de 1627*
>
> *[...]*
>
> *A 10, amaneció en casa de un barbero, en la plazuela de los Herradores, una campana, y en el portalón un altar que había hecho los Padres de la Compañía de Jesús para fundar allí una Iglesia, de que había de ser patrón el Duque de Lerma, que les compró toda aquella manzana para labrar la casa Profesa.*
>
> Anónimo, "Noticias de Madrid", 1621 - 1627 (España).

He encontrado un texto bastante anterior, que podría suponer un uso de un paso intermedio entre *maison* y *manzana* en un documento notarial, que pongo aquí en grado de tentativa porque realmente no estoy seguro de a qué se refiere con *mençana*:

> *[...] e ovimos aquirido e tonado el solar de la dicha torre e casa fuerte de Çahalguibar e sus tierras e huerto e mençana e los solares de la ferreria masuquera e molinos de Çahalguibar, que son çerca del dicho solar [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Carta de venta [Colección documental del Archivo Municipal de Mondragón]", 1451 (España).

Curiosamente, la forma antigua de denominar a las manzanas era con el sustantivo *isla*, como atestiguan algunos textos del siglo XVI y también Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611:

> No solo se llaman islas las que estan cercadas de aguas, pero tambien las casas que estan edificadas sin que otra ninguna se les pegue, siendo essentas de todas partes.

Esto me lleva a un texto del siglo XIX, anterior al arquitecto Ildelfons Cerdà que supuestamente repopularizó la palabra, que dice (negritas mías):

> *La catedral de Sevilla es uno de los mayores y mas suntuosos templos de España. Está situada al mediodia de la ciudad en el quartel A, barrio I, manzana 13. Se le agregan por el lado del norte el patio de los naranjos con sus oficinas, el sagrario nuevo y su sacristia: por el este la torre ó giralda, la capilla real y la contaduría mayor; y por el sur la sala capitular, la sacristia mayor, la sacristia de los calices, y lo que llaman el muro. **Todo junto forma una isla ó manzana**, rodeada de una espaciosa lonja, á la que se sube por escalinatas ó gradas en las fachadas del norte, poniente y parte de levante, á causa de la desigualdad del terreno; y está al piso de la calle en la del mediodia, y en la otra parte del oriente, cerrando esta lonja trozos de columnas, unos de edificios romanos, y otros modernos.*
>
> Juan Agustín Ceán Bermúdez, "Descripción artística de la catedral de Sevilla", 1804 (España).

Dado que el citado arquitecto nació en 1815, se entiende que la palabra *manzana* seguía siendo usada en el siglo XIX en tratados de arquitectura antes de que el señor Cerdá la usara para diseñar Barcelona.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que la palabra viene del francés **maison (casa)** y al parecer esta se deformó en el siglo XIX creando la palabra **Mansana** y posteriormente a **Manzana**

> [1] La palabra "**mansana**" la cual fue popularizada por Ildelfons Cerdà inspirándose en la idea del **manso feudal**, la cual se refería a la agrupación de porciones de tierra cedidas por el señor feudal a las que rodeaban las casas de los siervos que las trabajaban.
>
> [2] La palabra **Manso** procede de dos usos populares: los derivados del término francés ‘maçon’(mason) (albañil) y de ‘maison’ (casa).

Fuentes

[1] https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manzana_(urbanismo)
[2] https://www.api.cat/noticias/por-que-se-llama-manzana-a-una-isla-de-casas/

Comment: No es posible que la deformación que comentas ocurriera en el siglo XIX si en el siglo XVIII ya se registraba "manzana" en el diccionario como "conjunto de casas".